# Suspicious traffic shows on nethogs but not netstat

Tags: 14.04

Recently I noticed my little Banana Pi Server running Ubuntu 14.04.2 a bit laggy, so I checked several stuff. CPU usage, memory all seem normal but nethogs give me a list like this!

```
PID   USER    PROGRAM        SENT      RECEIVED
 ?    root    192.168.1.xxx:6958-106.8.160.1xx:2949       0.032   0.038 KB/sec
 ?    root    192.168.1.xxx:6958-183.170.160.xxx:631539   0.021   0.025 KB/sec
 ?    root    ..120:6958-94.201.84:65313                  0.000   0.000 KB/sec
```

There are more than 40 similar traffic, all going to different IP:port pair with small traffic like above list...

As you can see, the process with PID "?" is connecting to all over the world without my approval.

The port 6958 is used by amule as I once set it up. I had specified 6958 as one of amule's I/O port. I am sure amule is not running and checked this with `ps aufx`.

Without a valid PID from `nethogs`, I cannot determine what this process is. Thus I run `netstat` to try to determine the PID.

However, neither `netstat` shows any traffic through port 6958, nor `ps aufx` shows any strange process (or I just not sure what should I looking for?)

(all command above issues with `sudo`.)

It looks really like some bot infested my machine and turned it into a zombie. and the bot is distribution and call home all the time...

So, what is it? How can I find it?  Please let me know if more information are needed....

Answer (score 2):

`nethogs` shows the PID `?` for traffic that isn't associated with any running process, like incoming traffic to a port on which no program is listening.

In your case that's most likely other amule peers trying to connect to you.

Comment: I see... So in this case, the chance of bot is low.... Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: What about lots of traffic on localhost?  *grin*