# NetHogs showing suspicious (outgoing) traffic to random ports from root on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, firewall, traffic, nethogs

Using NetHogs on an Ubuntu 16.04 (web) server, i.e. on a machine where no consumer applications or web browsers are installed, besides traffic that is to be expected (HTTP and SSH)

```
 PID USER     PROGRAM                                           DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
5266 www-data /usr/sbin/apache2                                 eth0      15.142       2.924 KB/sec
4698 <ME>     sshd: <ME>@pts/0                                  eth0       0.899       0.071 KB/sec
```

I’m also seeing quite a few suspicious connections that look like this:

```
 PID USER     PROGRAM                                           DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
   ? root     <SERVER_IP_V4>:515-122.228.XXX.XXX:43652                     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ? root     <SERVER_IP_V4>:4946-92.118.XXX.XXX:44243                     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ? root     <SERVER_IP_V4>:1703-94.177.XXX.XXX:51820                     0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ? root     <SERVER_IP_V4>:1433-123.207.XXX.XXX:45628                    0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ? root     <SERVER_IP_V4>:34568-223.71.XXX.XXX:40922                    0.000       0.011 KB/sec
   ? root     <SERVER_IP_V4>:9444-51.91.XXX.XXX:46170                      0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ? root     unknown TCP                                                  0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

So they have no associated process ID [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593831/suspicious-traffic-shows-on-nethogs-but-not-netstat), are all run by `root`, seem to be outgoing connections from random-looking ports to other random-looking ports (i.e. no outgoing HTTP requests [[2]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91055/how-to-tell-if-mysterious-programs-in-nethogs-listing-are-malware) [[3]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/tons-of-unknown-connections-in-nethogs)), have no associated device, and all have little to no traffic [[4]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100112/nethogs-shows-0-kb-although-i-have-traffic).

The geographic origins of the destination addresses seem to be China, Russian Federation and Seychelles, among others, as per `whois`.

My firewall rules, as per `ufw status verbose`, should actually block any incoming traffic except for SSH and HTTP(S). So these outgoing connections would have to be caused by malicious programs running on the host, right?

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Is this indeed suspicious or perhaps even evidence of malicious traffic, or are these some false positives (for some reason I may not be seeing)?

Or is the order of the two IP addresses in each pair not relevant [[5]](https://serverfault.com/questions/792929/why-is-my-centos-7-system-making-connections-to-ripe-ip-addresses) [[6]](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4dhq4h/please_help_strange_connections_transmitting_data/), so that these might in fact be *incoming* connections? If so, how can this happen if UFW has been configured to block such connections, and how can one of these connections even have data transferred?

Comment: I think this link may be the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91055/456032

Answer (score 0):

This question is outdated, but I think you can accept this link as an explanation.

[unix.stackexchange.com/q/91055/456032](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91055/456032)